# bootstrap navbar-collapse wont toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="target1">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <li class="brand hidden-phone" data-target="#"><span style="padding-left: 40px">XXX-XXXX</span></li>
    <li class="brand hidden-phone"><span style="padding-left: 40px">XXX-XXX-XXXX</span></li>        
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse">
            <span class="icon-white icon-bar"></span>
            <span  class="icon-white icon-bar"></span>
            <span  class="icon-white icon-bar"></span>
        </a>

    <span class="nav nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="contact.php"><i class="icon-white icon-envelope"></i><strong>Mail Us</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/livechat/client.php"><i class="icon-white icon-comment"></i><strong>Live Chat</strong></a></li>
        <li class="hidden-phone"><a href=""><i class="icon-white icon-globe"></i><strong>Remote</strong></a></li></ul>
        <li><a href="#approach"><strong>Our Approach</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"><strong>Services</strong></a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:20px"><a href="#aboutus"><strong>About Us</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="../pricing/"><strong>Pricing</strong></a></li>
        </ul></span>

    </div>
</nav>
```

This navbar wont collapse or toggle to collapse Any ideas or suggestions??

accordion, scroll spy and other java scripts work in the way they should only problem is with navbar
bootstrap js and css added

Comment: Please can you add a fiddle

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid as all get-out.  Try just getting rid of the two `<li class="brand hidden-phone" ...` - or at least change them to DIVs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target is wrong. It should be

```
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

Comment: sorry, it was my bad some how figured it out... Thanks for all your hlep